# Bluetooth web control led stripe

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, led, web-bluetooth

Was using the Happylighting application on android and I try to make a simple web application to control the led color, but can't figure how to do it, and witch 'gatt' I've to request, I'm really new to bluetooth thing.

UPDATED I know with service is available thanks to a android sniffer

```
const service = "0000ffd5-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
const characteristic = "0000ffd9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" 



function onRequestBluetoothDeviceButtonClick() {
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
        filters: [{name:"QHM-0A0B"}],
        optionalServices: [service],
    })
    .then(device => {
        return device.gatt.connect()
    }).then(server =>{
        return server.getPrimaryService(service);
    }).then(service =>{
        return service.getCharacteristics(characteristic);
    }).then(characteristic=>{
        let colorArray = Uint8Array.from([86, 0, 255, 0, 25, 240, 170]);
        return characteristic[0].writeValue(colorArray);
    }).then(()=>{
        console.log("Send")
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Argh! ' + error);
    });
  }
```

But I don't figure what's next to send data to this and what is byte array mentionned in the git repo

Here is image : we console.log the characteristique
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share the api documentation you found?

Comment: Ofc @MichaelKotzjan here : https://web.dev/bluetooth/.

Comment: oh, you meant the bluetooth api. We would need the bluetooth api for your leds to give you hints. Did I understand you correctly, you want to replicate the Happylighting app using a web application?

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan It's exactly the point but I doesn't find only ressources to achieve this

Comment: What kind of Bluetooth-enabled led are you trying to control?

Comment: That's the question, I'm on https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B08YXQWLS3/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1, but non information online @MichaelKotzjan

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan Actually I don't understand what is written cause I'm not familiar with python and this kind of math but I saw this online https://github.com/MikeCoder96/HappyLighting-py/blob/master/LEDStripController/LEDStripController.py

Comment: Please add a `console.log()` line in every `.then(()=>{})`bracket and add the log output to your question. Something on the way goes wrong if you do not receive your `send` message

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan I uploaded the console log of characteristique

Comment: Have you tried doing the same using nRF Connect as I suggested?

Comment: I've tried but actually nothing append

Comment: That's what I feared. If you do not manage to change the color using an existing BLE app you can't expect to change it using your code. Maybe the library you found is outdated and the data format is not correct. There is no way of telling without a documentation of your device

Answer (score 0):

You already have the relevant UUID of the characteristic to write to from the github repository you posted in the comments. The repository also tells us how to compose the data to send using the colors we want.

These are the relevant lines:

```
print("RED: ")
red = int(input())
print("GREEN: ")
green = int(input())
print("BLUE: ")
blue = int(input())
lista = [86, red, green, blue, (int(10 * 255 / 100) & 0xFF), 256-16, 256-86]
values = bytearray(lista)
```

`values` will then be written to the device. So if we wanted to set the color green, our `lista` would contain the values `red = 0`, `green = 255` and `blue = 0` and look like this:

`[86, 0, 255, 0, 25, 240, 170]` or `5600FF0019F0AA` in hex.

In fact, only the second, third and fourth number will need to change to a value between 0 and 255 if we want different colors.

Now to start setting the color on your LED device please always start using a generic BLE scanner tool like [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to test the connection before attempting to write something yourself. When scanning using the tool you should be able to find your led device and connect to it. After scanning the services you should find a characteristic with the UUID `0000ffd9-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`. Write the value `5600FF0019F0AA` to it and see if your device turns green.

Now that this is working and you understand how to compose the data you can start working on your own code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I've updated the post using what I understand from you and the console, but still not working, I've no clue why since no error is displayed

Comment: I add an img to show you somehting I didn't see first but when I read from upper characteristique I saw this

Comment: @BeatlesBOB that's a screenshot from nRF Connect. What exactly do you want to show me?

Comment: I thought maybe with the first characteristique that show invalid data, we could know what's going wrong

Comment: @BeatlesBOB I can't without access to the device. Trying to access BLE characteristics without documentation is always only a try-and-error process. If you are unsuccessful using nRF Connect you could try to get your handy on a BLE sniffer and log the communication between your smartphone and the device to reverse engineer it. But I can't help you anymore